# How to query logicblox

Tags: sql, logicblox, logiql

I have an entity predicate eg. "Person" with related functional predicates storing attributes about the entity.

Eg.

```
Person(x), Person:id(x:s) -> string(s).

Person:dateOfBirth[a] = b -> Person(a), datetime(b).
Person:height[a] = b -> Person(a), decimal(b).
Person:eyeColor[a] = b -> Person(a), string(b).
Person:occupation[a] = b -> Person(a), string(b).
```

What I would like to do is in the terminal, do the equivalent of the SQL query:

```
SELECT id, dateOfBirth, eyeColor FROM Person
```

I am aware of the print command to get the details of a single functional predicate, but I would like to get a combination of them.

```
lb print /workspace 'Person:dateOfBirth'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the "lb query" command to execute arbitrary logiql queries against your database. Effectively you create a temporary, anonymous, predicate with the results you want to see, and then a rule for populating that predicate using the logiql language. So in your case it would be something like:

```
lb query <workspace> '_(id, dob, eye) <- 
  Person(p),
  Person:id(p:id),
  Person:dateOfBirth[p] = dob,
  Person:eyeColor[p] = eye.'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the query command with joins:

`lb query /workspace '_(x, y, z) <- Person(p), Person:id(p:x), Person:dateOfBirth[p] = y, Person:eyeColor[p] = z.'`